# How to convert Vec to JsonValue in Rust

Tags: json, rust, rust-rocket

I am querying my database and getting an `Vec<Bookable>` struct, using diesel library.

```
#[derive(QueryableByName)]
pub struct Bookable {
  #[sql_type = "BigInt"]
  pub id: i64,
  #[sql_type = "Text"]
  pub title: String
}
```

When I query the elements, I can access the result, but it's not possible to convert the `Vec<Bookable>` to `json!` macro:

```
pub fn get_terms(conn: &MysqlConnection) -> Vec<Bookable> {
  diesel::sql_query(r#"SELECT title, LAST_INSERT_ID() 'id' from bookable_term;"#)
    .load::<Bookable>(conn).expect("Query failed")
}
```

And later I call it this way:

```
  let conn = connect();
  let terms = bookable::get_terms(&conn);
  json!({ "data": {
    "items": terms }
  })
```

The question is how to put the terms into this object and send the whole array to the API? I can stringify a json like this:

```
"items:" &vec!["to", "be", "or", "not", "to", "be"]
```

But when it comes to an existing Vec I get compiler error. I am using `Rocket` so it provides a `rocket_contrib::json::JsonValue` which holds `json!` macro

Comment: If you have a `struct Response { items: Vec<Bookable> }` where `Bookable` and `Response` impl `serde::Deserialize` (e.g. via a derive) you should be able to return a `rocket_contrib::json::Json<Response>` right away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you derive your struct like -

```
use serde::{Deserialize, Serialize};
use std::collections::HashMap;
use rocket_contrib::{json::{Json}};

#[derive(QueryableByName, Deserialize, Serialize)]
pub struct Bookable {
  #[sql_type = "BigInt"]
  pub id: i64,
  #[sql_type = "Text"]
  pub title: String
}
```

Then you can do something like -

```
 let conn = connect();
 let terms = bookable::get_terms(&conn);
 let mut data: Vec<Bookable> = HashMap::new();
 data.insert("data", terms);
 return Json(Vec<Bookable>);
```

`Json(Vec<Bookable>)` will also set the content-type as json for the response.